# Caching url with the same html file, independent of the query string parameters

Tags: javascript, caching, service, progressive-web-apps, worker

I need that my service worker, when receiving a url `[app-domain].com/some-update-page?id=[id]`, returns, in case of offline browsing, always the same cached html file `some-update-page.html`, and the parameter `[id]` arrives as a value that can be stored in a js variable, since I have all the related information stored in IndexedDb. What is the way to achieve this? Thus, caching the html it contains the entire logic, I can work with all the database data stored on the client side without problems.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Which part are you struggling with?  Detecting if offline, splitting apart a querystring, using a client-side database?

Comment: The real problem is that, for example: `[app-domain].com/some-update-page?Id=1` is cached correctly and works offline once it is stored in cache. Obtaining the `[id]` and storing it as a javascript variable does not bring any problems of course. However, when I enter the url `[app-domain].com/some-update-page?Id=2`, although the page I need is exactly the same, it tells me that _there is no Internet connection_, because it detects a different url . I need that regardless of the id, the cache that works offline will return the same page. Am I being a little clearer now?

Comment: I don’t think that will work unless you rewrite the caching system.  your best bet is likely save the page locally and use a local url to access it with different querystring params

Answer (score 0):

In your service worker, handle the `fetch` event. You might already have a handler, in which case you'll need to fit some more logic into the existing handler. The exact way you do that depends on how your service worker is currently designed, and it might be out of scope for this question.

In the handler, look at the request URL's path, disregarding the query parameters. You can use the `URL` constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL to parse out the path, for example. That way, you can see if the path matches this page even if something like `?Id=2` was in the original request.

Then respond to the fetch event with a copy of the `some-update-page.html` file. You can use a `fetch` call to retrieve it from either the network or from the browser's built in cache, or use something like `CacheStorage` if you want special assurances about offline availability.